# How to organize pandas dataframe columns based on smallest to greatest values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

So I have some code that imports a sample csv file:

```
 import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/benitocano/Downloads/airtravel.csv')
df.columns = ['Month', '1', '2', '3']

df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
count = 0
for i in df.index:
    d = pd.DataFrame()
    d = df.iloc[[count]]
    count = count + 1

[df.iloc[[i]] for i in range(len(df))]
```

It then organizes to make each individual row a new dataframe, with an out that looks like:

```
[         1    2  3
 Month             
 JAN    360  417  0,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 FEB    342  391  1,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 MAR    406  419  2,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 APR    396  461  3,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 MAY    420  472  4,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 JUN    472  535  5,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 JUL    548  622  6,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 AUG    559  606  7,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 SEP    463  508  8,
          1    2  3
 Month             
 OCT    407  461  9,
          1    2   3
 Month              
 NOV    362  390  10,
          1    2   3
 Month              
 DEC    405  432  11]
```

My question is how do I order each dataframes' columns so that their values are arranged smallest to greatest?

Comment: have you checked https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Yes, though when I looked I could not find out how to do it so that the columns were re arranged rather than the rows (this is most likely because of my inexperience, though it is why I cam here to ask the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your last code line by:

```
[df.loc[[i]].sort_values(by = i, axis = 1) for i in df.index]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with selecting with `[]` for `Series` and then [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
[df.loc[i].sort_values(i).to_frame() for i in df.index]
```

Your solution is changed by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `axis=1` for sorting by `i` index values:

```
[df.iloc[[i]].sort_values(by=df.index[i], axis=1) for i in range(len(df))]
```